# increase-memory-limit command not found

Tags: node.js, heap-size

I wanted to increase the heap size of my node project. So I installed [increase-memory-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/increase-memory-limit) package.

But when I execute `increase-memory-limit` in the terminal I get an error of  "increase-memory-limit: command not found". Please help me if I am missing something.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need a module for that.

Just pass a value to the [`--max_old_space_size` V8 flag](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/flag-definitions.h#L683) when you're starting up your server. For example, if you're using `index.js` as the entry point and you want 2048 MB of managed heap you would do:

```
$ node --max_old_space_size=2048 index.js
```

Do note that V8 flags should be declared *before* the file you want to run.